# speeding up my mysql statement

Tags: mysql, performance, select, virtual

I have the following table:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| t                   | price |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2013-04-22 13:23:51 |  9.42 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Where t is type timestamp and price is float.

The table is big and is around 500K rows.

Task:

I am going to show the table and the MIN price of past 3 days for EACH row.

So I wrote the following:

```
select *,(
  select max(b.price)
  from my_table b 
  where b.t<a.t and date(b.t)>=adddate(date(a.t),-3)
) from my_table a;
```

The problem is that it nevers complete my query and it looks like it hung.... Is there any way to speeed up the query?  Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Do you have an `index` on `timestamp`? That will help significantly

Comment: yes, I have t set as index.

Answer (score 0):

I think your adddate function might be incorrect.  Try using it like this: ADDDATE(a.t, INTERVAL -3 DAY)

Comment: I just tried again with a lot less rows, but the speed is also weired:

mysql> select count(*) from my_table where date(t)=date(now());

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      634 |
+----------+


mysql> SELECT a.t, a.price, ( SELECT MAX(b.price) FROM my_table b    WHERE b.t BETWEEN a.t - INTERVAL 3 DAY and a.t - INTERVAL 1 SECOND ) from my_table a WHERE date(t)=date(now());

Comment: Are you not able to join tables a and b together?  It basically looks like you are wanting to grab all the data from each table and put it in one table but sql doesn't know how to match it up.  I would try joining and then do select *, max(b.price) from ......

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
select *,(
  select max(b.price)
  from my_table b 
  where b.t between a.t - interval 3 day and a.t - interval 1 second
) from my_table a;
```

and make sure my_table.t has an index:

```
alter table my_table add index ix_t (t);
```

Comment: Hi Ross,

Thanks for your answer, I added index to my table, but still the running time take ages (more than 15 mins and I finally had to break it).....

So, any other solutions that will run faster?

Answer (score 0):

This query should work fast:

```
SELECT *,
    (   SELECT max(b.price)
        FROM my_table b
        WHERE b.t > a.t - interval 3 day
          AND b.t < a.t
    )
FROM my_table a
```

but you need to make sure that you have an index on `mytable(t)` - I assume that this field is `timestamp` or `datetime`.